# Can't import controls from a dll in vs2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, controls

I've a dll containing some controls that I can import to my toolbox in VS2010. However when it comes to VS2012, I cannot import that into my toolbox.

How can I import it?

To be specific, I'm using the [MetroUI](https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui) and trying to import those metro controls.

Comment: What framework are you using 2012 and what on 2010 on the specific project?

Comment: I'm not sure. However that project supports .net45. That's all I know.

Comment: If the dll is for .net 4 and your project is for 4.5 it can not be imported. **EDIT** You should know what framework you r using :)

Comment: I misinterpreted your word "project". Here's the correction: my project is in net40 and the dll supports 30, 35, 40, 45. I tried all of these dlls. All of them can be imported into vs2010 while none can be imported into vs2012.